# How do I freeze a form until an action has been done on the first form

Tags: c#, .net, forms

I have 2 forms.. form1 & form2

I would like to freeze form2 until the user has pressed a button on form1..

What methods could I be using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Next time please review your own question and try yourself if you can understand what you have just ask..

as far as i understand you want to open up form2 as soon as form1 is opened, however you want to keep form2 "enabled=false".

you can try the following and see if it matches your expectations:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.Show();
        f2.Enabled = false;

        button1.Click += delegate { f2.Enabled = true; };
    }

}
```